# How to print all of the variables and their type inside a function

Tags: python, function, variables

I know that I could use `locals()` or `globals()` to either get all of the local or global variables used in a Python script environment, but does Python have a keyword that I can use to call only the variables inside a function?

For example:

```
def function():
    a = 3;
    b = 4;
    c = float(b+a)

>> keyword(function())
>> [a : <class 'int'>, b : <class 'int'>, c : <class 'float'>]
```

Comment: Are you unable to modify the function?

Comment: What do you mean "variables and their type"? Python variables don't _have_ a type, they can store arbitrary objects. What if I do `a = 1; a = 2.5; a = 'foo'; a = object()`, what would `a`'s type be?

Comment: Yes @Aran-Fey, you are right. Actually this should be more a question about Keras, where build neural layers which have already a type (convolutional, rnn, etc) however I was also interested into making it in a general way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
# define these outside the scope of the function
x = 10
y = 20

def function():
    a = 3;
    b = 4;
    c = float(b+a)
    l = locals()
    print(", ".join(["{var}: {type}".format(var=v, type=type(l[v])) for v in l]))

function()
#a: <type 'int'>, c: <type 'float'>, b: <type 'int'>
```

Comment: Yes @pault, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the function, you could return the values and then check their types. If you are unable to modify the function, I don't think you can assume what the variables types are.

```
def function():
    a = 3
    b = 4
    c = float(a + b)
    return a, b, c

x, y, z = function()

type(x), type(y), type(z)
```